# xmlrpc User Credentials are not Authentic logic

Tags: php, web-services, authentication, xml-rpc, http-status-codes

Ok I'm following this tutorial for a basic PHP webservice server/client setup:

http://www.java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=1186

Now I'm wanting to add a user authentication and have the functionality working but wanted to know if the user doesn't authenticate how can I return an http Status 401 Unauthorized?

I'm not using HTTP to authenticate (using user,pass and salt against a database) but have the functionality working for this. Is there something I can set to notify http that the user is not authorised? Or am I looking at this the wrong way?

Thanks for any helpful tips

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`401` is specifically designed to signal the use of HTTP authentication. `401 Unauthorized` responses MUST include a `WWW-Authenticate`, but the opposite is not true.

Comment: the question is valid. it's the usage of the 401 header that's invalid.